# Running nodetool resetlocalschema causes exceptions complaining system_auth keyspace doesn't exist

Tags: cassandra

I have a 15 node cassandra 3.9 cluster. I recently faced an issue where one of my nodes as piling up GossipStage messages. Following some guidance I found on a similar report I ran 'nodetool resetlocalschema' on that node. While gossip errors like these continue to show in the logs

```
WARN  [GossipTasks:1] 2018-02-11 23:55:34,197 Gossiper.java:771 - Gossip stage has 180317 pending tasks; skipping status check (no nodes will be marked down)
```

I also see the following exception. Any guidance on how I can overcome this and bring this node back to normal? Also I should mention I have PasswordAuthenticator enabled in the cassandra.yaml file.

```
ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2018-02-11 23:55:33,581 Message.java:617 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0xbaa65545, 
L:/10.1.21.51:9042 - R:/10.1.86.40:35082]
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown keyspace
/cf pair (system_auth.roles)
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator.authenticate(PasswordAuthenticator.java:107) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator.access$300(PasswordAuthenticator.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator$PlainTextSaslAuthenticator.getAuthenticatedUser(PasswordAuthenticator.java:220) ~[ap
ache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.AuthResponse.execute(AuthResponse.java:78) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:513) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:407) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Fi
nal]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar
:4.0.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.
Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Fina
l]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) [apache
-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown keyspace/cf pair (system_auth.roles)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2203) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.AuthCache.get(AuthCache.java:108) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator.authenticate(PasswordAuthenticator.java:88) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Not sure why someone would have recommended, resetlocalschema. Anyways restart the node that is having problem and it will catch up & refresh schema on its way back up.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried that already, and it does not seem to help. I am continually seeing the above mentioned errors flood the logs and they wont subside. And nodetool status has marked the node DN. Anything else that I can try?

Comment: can you paste the output of "nodetool describecluster" here? Get this from all nodes in your cluster.

Comment: The output is long. So I will split it across multiple comments.

Comment: The nodes in my cluster range in ips ending 41-55. Node 42 was recently removed from the cluster. And 51 is the rogue node that I am trying to contend with.

Comment: **.*.**.48:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.42, **.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.50:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.42, **.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.51:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      59adb24e-f3cd-3e02-97f0-5b395827453f: [**.*.**.51]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.42]

Comment: **.*.**.53:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.41:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.45:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.55:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.42, **.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.42:
    nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.

Comment: **.*.**.43:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.42, **.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.44:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.46:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.42, **.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.52:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.42, **.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.47:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.42, **.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.54:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.51]

Comment: **.*.**.49:
    Cluster Information:
     Name: ProfessorX
     Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
     Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     Schema versions:
      a10c91e2-8b32-3481-8661-533168cf76f6: [**.*.**.41, **.*.**.43, **.*.**.45, **.*.**.44, **.*.**.47, **.*.**.46, **.*.**.49, **.*.**.48, **.*.**.50, **.*.**.53, **.*.**.52, **.*.**.55, **.*.**.54]
    
      UNREACHABLE: [**.*.**.42, **.*.**.51]

Comment: can you please add this info by editing your question and not over 15 comments :)

Comment: Looks like 42 node ip still seems to be part of the ring. Use "nodetool removenode" to explicitly take it out of the cluster gossip. For node 51 - shutdown the node, inside the cassandra data directory rename the folder  system to "system-old" ; "system_auth" to system_auth_old" and restart that node.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this issue was resolved by simply restarting the seed nodes of my cluster first followed by the rest of the nodes in my cluster. Thanks for all the inputs. Truly appreciate it.